# meyvn - mdl-selectfield - Error when using change method

Tags: javascript, material-design

I am trying to dynamically change the value of the following selectfield ([https://github.com/meyvn/mdl-selectfield](https://stackoverflow.com)) using the built-in change method.

```
<div class="mdl-selectfield mdl-js-selectfield mdl-selectfield--floating-label" id="changecalColordiv">
    <select id="changecalColor" name="changecalColor" class="mdl-selectfield__select">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="#73CEE1">1</option>
        <option value="#B3D334">2</option>
    </select>
    <label for="changecalColor" class="mdl-selectfield__label">Category</label>
</div>
```

I try to change the value with the following call:

```
document.getElementById('changecalColor').parentElement.MaterialSelectfield.change(response.color);
```

This works so far, but then I get the following additional error message in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
> at e.update_ (mdl-selectfield.min.js:1:2184)
> at e.change_ (mdl-selectfield.min.js:1:10320)
> at Object.<anonymous> (groupcalendarofficial.php:546:89)
> at u (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:27457)
> at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:28202)
> at k (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:77651)
> at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:79907)

Line in mdl-selectfield.min.js:

```
this.listOptionBox_.querySelector("." +this.CssClasses_.IS_SELECTED).classList.remove(this.CssClasses_.IS_SELECTED)
```

However, this error message now leads to the suppression of my remaining JS code and thus prevents my website from functioning.
Now I would like to ask if anyone has any ideas as to what the problem could be. Am I using the wrong call or could it be that there is a faulty implementation of the change method?

As I have been trying to get this construct to work for weeks now, I hope that someone else is smarter than me.
Many thanks in advance!

Also tried to use

```
document.getElementById('changecalColor').parentNode.MaterialSelectfield.change(response.color);
```